# can not add other get variable in php mvc

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

I'm using this .htaccess code

```
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this is my PHP

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
            $url = rtrim($url, '/');
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            if(empty($url[0])){
```

etc.

Now I need to add new `GET` variable in htaccess
I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but nothing happenned because I do not understand how to check `$_GET['lang']` variable
when it may or may not exist. Also `$_GET['url']` variable may be a string such as
`categories,companynane,employee`
or it might only be `categories` or `categories,companyname` or may be `NULL`.

I do not understand how to check this lang variable from the link like this:
http://mydomain.com/categories/companynane/employee/en

it is my updated class.

```
<?php
    class Bootstrap {    
        public function __construct(){
            $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
            $url = rtrim($url, '/');
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            if(empty($url[0])){
                require Controllers.'main.php';
                $controller = new main();
                $controller->Index();
                return false;
            }
            $file = Controllers.$url[0].'.php';
            if(file_exists($file)){
                require $file;
            }else{
                $this->error();
            }
            $controller = new $url[0];
            $controller->loadmodel($url[0]);
            if(isset($url[3])){
                $_SESSION['lang'] = $url[3];
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                    $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
                }else{
                    $this->error();
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($url[2])){
                    $testinglang = $this->_new->checklang($url[2]);
                    if($testinglang == true){
                        $_SESSION['lang'] = $url[2];
                        if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                            $controller->{$url[1]}();
                        }else{
                            $this->error();
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                            $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
                        }else{
                            $this->error();
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($url[1])){
                        $testinglang = $this->_new->checklang($url[1]);
                        if($testinglang == true){
                            $_SESSION['lang'] = $url[1];
                            $controller->Index();
                        }else{
                            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                                $controller->{$url[1]}();
                            }else{
                                $this->error();
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        $controller->Index();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function error(){
            require Controllers.'error.php';
            $controller = new error();
            $controller->Index();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I think everything is good except $url[0].
what about if $url[0] exists and is language?
or may be it is controller
please tell me how to check this.

Comment: if above code works then try RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ index.php?url=$1&lang=$2 [QSA,L]

Comment: may be it will be work
but I do not understand how to check this variable from PHP

Comment: you can use $_GET or $_REQUEST for get query strings

Comment: The same way you checked `url` use isset($_GET['lang'])

Answer (score 0):

In order to use $2 you need another pair of ()
So I guess you want something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&lang=$2 [QSA,L]
```

That would match http://mydomain.com/categories/en

Then you can do in php:

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : null;
if ($lang == 'en') {
    // do something in english
}
```

After we ironed out your real problem, this should help:

Leave the RewriteRule as it was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In php do after the code to fill $url:

```
$lang = array_pop($url);
```

array_pop returns the last element of an array. In your case this is the language. After that it will no longer be in $url, but you have $lang no matter how your URL looks like.

Comment: and nothing else?
it is very simple.
oh I`m angry to my mind.
thank you.
I`ll try this and will write here after that.

Comment: That will not work for the given example of `http://mydomain.com/categories/companynane/employee/en`

Comment: You might run into more problems if you have more than one / in your url like in http://mydomain.com/categories/companynane/employee/en. You need a more sophisticated rewrite rule then. This highly depends on how exactly your URLs are build up.

Comment: it is not working.
I do not understand
I have only 2 variables
1) url
2) lang
in url I have string with commas and with PHP I`m converting it in array 
and in lang I have only 2 cariants.
lang not exists and it is.
I do not understand any more what to do.
Please HELP

Comment: I'm not sure yet what you really want to do. Maybe you need to post more code in your question. If you just want the language from the url above, it already is in $url[4] since $_GET['url'] is splittet by /.

Comment: yes. it is $url[4] in this example
but may be in the $url be nothing or only categories or only categories and companyname
I do not know how it will be.
understand now?
I need to check the last value.

Comment: I add my updated class in the first post. please look at it and help me.